# undefined not treated as falsy in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
const f = (x: number) => { }

const a : (number | undefined)[] = [1,undefined,3];

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
    if (a[i]) {
        f(a[i]);
    }
}
```

In the example above, `a` is an array that can hold an element which can be either number of undefined.

In the loop, I want to only access the element if it is not undefined. My understanding is that `if (a[i])` would filter every undefined values (also 0 too, but let's not think of that here).

So I *thought* the typescript would think the type of `a[i]` inside the `if` would be simply `number`. But if I get this error when calling `f`.

```
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
'x' is declared but its value is never read.
```

Why is the type of `a[i]` cannot be deduced to `number` with the `if` check above?

Comment: It's a known problem: TS does not work through reference: `a[i]` is not treated as the same thing. Assigning to a variable and using that `let item = a[i];` will work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work fine, it is because typescript does not deduce what type a[i] would result in, in the if condition itself. Creating a variable and then checking the same would work. This is a known issue as you can access both arrays and object with the square bracket [].

```
const f = (x: number) => { }

const a : (number | undefined)[] = [1,undefined,3];

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
    let j = a[i];
    if (j) {
        f(j);
    }
}
```